# On-Session-expire-event?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I'm programming an MVC3 application. Now I hava to call a script if the users session expire.

Is there something like a event on-session-expire, that get fired when the user session expired?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Did you try `Session_End` event in global.aspx ?

Comment: By *session expire* you mean ASP.NET session expiration or authentication cookie expiration?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In your `Global.asax`
you can create a

```
protected void Session_End(object sender, EventArgs e) { }
```

method which should be called when a session ends.

Comment: It is worth mentioning that this event is never triggered if you use out of process session state. It works only with InProc mode.