# how to save session expiry time to sql server using c# in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

I'm  using session in asp.net. I set session expiry 1 min. I need to save the expiry time to sql server.
Please help me!
Thank you in advance.

```
<system.web>
    <sessionState timeout="1"/>
</system.web>
```

Comment: refer to this [Mdm HttpSessionState.Timeout Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.sessionstate.httpsessionstate.timeout(v=vs.110).aspx). You can get the value and store it in your database.

Comment: Before asking, please research the solution for your problem first.[Session Expired event][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8488824/on-session-expire-event