# How to logout from XMPP while closing any browser in c#?

Tags: c#, xmpp

I want to logout or close my connection from XMPP while user are no longer in my website.

My question is: do I have to write some jquery event for that or do ajax call ?

I wrote this code in my logout button click event.

```
XmppClient client = (XmppClient)Session["XMPP"];
if (client != null)
{
  client.Close();
  client.Dispose();
}
```

I dont know if any event is available in `Global.asax` file.

Or provide another way to do that, please.

Answer (score 0):

See the answer here: [Javascript register window/tab closing event before window/tab close](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2584124/javascript-register-window-tab-closing-event-before-window-tab-close#2584131).

Using the `window.onbeforeunload` ([MDN article](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowEventHandlers/onbeforeunload)) event, you can assign an event listener to fire off an AJAX call that can finalize your `XmppClient`:

```
window.onbeforeunload = function (event) {
    $.ajax('/api/route/specifically/to/finalize/xmpp')
};
```

Of course, be sure to check that the [browser compatibility (MDN)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowEventHandlers/onbeforeunload#Browser_compatibility) is what you require. Edge, for example, does not support this event. IE is apparently iffy when it comes to that specific event handler. You can also refer to an alternative ["beforeunload" event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/beforeunload) that is [apparently more widely supported](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/beforeunload#Browser_compatibility). It would look like this:

```
window.addEventListener("beforeunload", function (event) {
    $.ajax('/api/route/specifically/to/finalize/xmpp')
});
```

Also be aware that this won't work if the browser crashed, for example, or some other unexpected event causes the window to close where the browser may not be able to fire that event before the window closes.

You might also consider the `Session_End` event in `Global.aspx`: [On-Session-expire-event?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8488824/on-session-expire-event) and [MSDN article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178583.aspx):

```
public void Session_OnEnd()
{
    Application.Lock();
    Application["UsersOnline"] = (int)Application["UsersOnline"] - 1;
    Application.UnLock();
}
```

That will run (according to MSDN) "when the Abandon method has been called or when the session has expired."